# listview adding spinner in each row?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-spinner

I am facing problem while putting `Spinner` in layout. My acctual requirement is to place `Spinner` once, at the top of layout.

This output I am getting:

[image]

I have Relative layout

```
   <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:entries="@array/string_array"
       android:prompt="@string/spinner_msg"
     />
     <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/notesTextView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
</TextView>`
```

`MyActivity` class is extended by `ListActivity` here's `onCreate` method

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     listView=getListView();
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
     spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
     getDetailsCursor();
    String[] from = new String[] {"db_column"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.notesTextView};
            curAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.mylist, null, from, to);
            setListAdapter(curAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
    }`
```

Comment: Do you want all the spinners on the top or? As i see it, the spinner is on top?

Comment: Please re-phrase your requirement and post your layout XML.

Comment: I want only one spinner on top. but it added three times by the listview Evilunclebill

Comment: @PSK Allright, your question didnt say that. Please, as kiljaTM asked, add you xml layouts.

Comment: It have added 3 spinners as it shows and from your comment you have said that you listview. So in this case you must have defined the spinner in your listview custom layout file that is why its adding 3 spinner with the 3 values of the text. check out your listview custom layout which you are inflating from your adapter class.

Comment: I have add layout file and code. please check this.

Comment: @Class Stacker I have add layout XML file and code. please check this.

Comment: The code snippet you now posted does not relate to your problem in a meaningful way.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake.. @Class Stacker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code in which spinner inflates on the top of listview :

```
listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mTop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin, null);
        authorityView.addHeaderView(mTop);
```

R.layout.spin   is that layout which contains only spinner.
And inside the List you have to inflate textView only. as you are doing in mylist.xml ,
just remove spinner from it and made seprate xml for spinner.

so spinner is once, at the top of layout (ListView).

Comment: if u like my answer plz appreciate my answer :)

Comment: Could tell me how I set up `onItemClickListener` on that Spinner.

Comment: just write   Spinner spin = mTop.findViewById(R.id.spinnerId);

Answer (score 0):

I have some difficulty making out what your actual question is, some layout.xml code would help here, too.  I think, that you are placing the spinner inside the listitem.xml instead of the main.xml, so that it gets replicated for each item in your listview. Please share some code.
Since you declare both the TextView and the Spinner in mylist.xml, you get both those elements in each Item of your List.
If you only want one spinner, you shouldn't use a ListActivity, but instead create a normal Activity with a Spinner and a ListView in the Layout. Then define another layout to use for the list items (e.g. with only the TextView).