# How to add a spinner against each item of list view

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have an activity where there is a list of players. The list contains all the player's name. I want to provide a spinner against each name with some options like "Remove", "Rate as best" etc.
I have created the list but not able to add a spinner with a certain set of options.

My code is.

```
public class AddPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.players_listView)
    ListView playersListView;

    // Adapter for playersListView
    private ArrayAdapter<String> playersArrayAdapter;

    // Array of the players to be loaded in the list view
    String[] players = {"ABC", "XYZ", "MNO", "GHI"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_player);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Initializing array adapter
        playersArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.players_name, players);
        playersListView.setAdapter(playersArrayAdapter);


        playersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_add_player.xml is-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_player">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:id="@+id/players_listView"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have spinner component in players_name.xml ? And instead of using default Adapter write customAdapter and use it as you wish.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002821/listview-adding-spinner-in-each-row in each row you can add sipner

Comment: Create a layout which will have TextView and Spinner inside a LinearLayout (orientation : horizontal).. Then use a custom adapter which will extend BaseAdapter. Now inflate this layout in your adapter.
Check this example on how to use custom adapter : http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/

Comment: It's Good for you to add spinner with each list item using Custom Adapter for List View.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on listview open Dialog and attach custom layout to the Dialog instead of spinner.

Ex:

Write below code inside listview clicklistner--

```
 final Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(Add_Vendor.this);
                        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_taglist);
                        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                        alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                        alertDialog.show();

                        list = (ListView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                        Button btndone  = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                        CustomAdapterTag cadapter = new CustomAdapterTag(Add_Vendor.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,     

                                 tagslist);        

                        list.setAdapter(cadapter);
```

and in this way you can use customAdaper with options like "Remove", "Rate as best" etc